# Replace end of varying string

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have tried dozens of various sed options but haven't found a combination that works yet. I am trying to turn:

```
test(3) = var
other(8) = var
test(13) = var
...
```

into:

```
test(3) = newvar
other(8) = var
test(13) = newvar
...
```

The problem I'm encountering is the varying value in the parentheses. I want to edit *after* the value, to prevent having to catch it and assign it. I tried the following, thinking I could use `.*` as a wildcard inside the parentheses, but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
sed -n "s/\(test(.*\)\s+\w+/\1) = newstuff/g" file.txt
```

Comment: Why not just do `s/var/newvar/`?

Comment: Sorry, this is a MWE, maybe slightly too simple. I can't do that because `var` is changing (`newvar` is stored in an array).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this sed command:

```
sed -i.bak 's/^\([^=]* *= *\).*$/\1newvar/' file
```

This will match RHS string (from start until `=` is found) and that is replaced by `newvar`

If you want to use a shell variable then use double quotes:

```
NEWVAR="something"
sed -i.bak "s/^\([^=]* *= *\).*$/\1$NEWVAR/" file
```

**UPDATE:** To change only lines starting with `test`:

```
sed -i.bak "s/^\( *test *[^=]* *= *\).*$/\1$NEWVAR/" file
```

Comment: Yup, this definitely works. I will mark as correct answer in 10 minutes (you're too fast for the system). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the update. It turns out this worked also:
`sed "s/^test\([^=]* *= *\).*$/test\1newvar/" file.txt`, but I think your method is cleaner.